# what is the purpose of `setInitialTrigger` on GeofencingRequest?

Tags: android, geofencing

I really don't understand the function `setInitialTrigger` on `GeofencingRequest` class.

I know that we can create some `Geofence` object whith different transition:

1. Enter
2. Exit
3. Dwell

Which is fine for me and acceptable.

Now, my problem is relatively to the class `GeofencingRequest` and more precisely the method `setInitialTrigger`.
I really don't understand the value that we should put there...
Android documentation ([here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)) isn't really helpful regarding to the meaning of that method.

Imagine that I have this piece of code:

```
private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
        builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
        return builder.build();
    }
```

What is the meaning of `GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER` ?

For me it means, that `GeofencingRequest` should trigger any `Geofence` object which have an **ENTER** transition.

But imagine that I have multiple Geofence with different behaviour ENTER or EXIT transition.

How should I handle/implement with GeofencingRequest Builder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

builder.setInitialTrigge Sets the **geofence notification behavior at the moment when the geofences are added.**

You can use 3 constants:

**public static final int INITIAL_TRIGGER_DWELL**

A flag indicating that geofencing service should trigger GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL notification at the moment when the geofence is added and if the device is already inside that geofence for some time.

Constant Value: 4

**public static final int INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER**

A flag indicating that geofencing service should trigger GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER notification at the moment when the geofence is added and if the device is already inside that geofence.

Constant Value: 1

**public static final int INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT**

A flag indicating that geofencing service should trigger GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT notification at the moment when the geofence is added and if the device is already outside that geofence.

Constant Value: 2

What is the meaning of GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER ?
INdicate that geofencing service should trigger at the moment when the geofence is added and if the device is already inside that geofence.

Check the difference is the time:

DWELL = is already inside that geofence for some time.

ENTER = is already inside that geofence.

EXIT = is already outside that geofence.

Comment: In this case, I can put the TRIGGER_ENTER and TRIGGER_EXIT to the setInitialTrigger method ?
Like that`setInitialTrigger(GeofenceRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTer | GeofenceRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT)` which will trigger every Geofence object added with an entrance transition or an exit ?

Comment: yes, it's a bit-wise of INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER and/or INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT and/or INITIAL_TRIGGER_DWELL, just like google says in https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingRequest.Builder

Comment: The first sentence is the answer. thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
`public GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest(Geofence geofence){
        return  new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
                .addGeofence(geofence)
                .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_DWELL|
                                   GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER|
                                   GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT)
                .build();
    }`
```

This function will trigger the `GeofenceRequest` when either of `ENTER`, `DWELL`, `EXIT` will take place